# How to update detail view if master view row data is changed in fragment context for Tablet UI

Tags: android, android-fragments

We have master view(1st fragment) that contains the list of employees showing row data like empno, emp name, emp id.. so on

If we will select any row, It will show the employee full details on detail view(2 fragment)

So here i am on emp101 details and emp name is "Jack". now i changed emp101 name to "Rocky" on master view(1st fragment) so how to update emp name on details view(2nd fragment).

Comment: Show you code. What are you currently doing